# How to scroll through command history of tmux?

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux

C-b:  gives you tmux command prompt.
Is there a way to scroll through the commands entered on it previously?
Up arrow or Ctrl p/n don't seem to work.

Comment: UP arrow works fine on my tmux...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> work in the *default* (Emacs) mode; if however, you have set `vi-mode` then you will need to either explicitly enter command mode (by pressing <kbd>Escape</kbd> once at tmux's command prompt—<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>:</kbd>), or you can create keybinds for those commands in your `.tmux.conf`, thereby removing the need to change modes:

```
set -g status-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-edit Up   history-up
bind-key -t vi-edit Down history-down
```

Tmux's default bindings can be seen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>,<kbd>:</kbd> and then entering `lsk -t vi-edit`. The defaults are, in this case:

```
bind-key -ct vi-edit   Up   history-up
bind-key -ct vi-edit   Down history-down
```

Note the `-ct` switch for command mode.